# Form action for external url's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to add direct to S3 uploading functionality to an app and ran into some issues regarding the form tag. I'm using this js library/tutorial https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-directly-to-S3 but am unable to mimic the HAML its using. More or less what I'd like to do is have

```
:action => "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

inside of the `form_tag`, but doing so simply ignores the url and winds up using the index action of the model. I am using a `form_for` rather than `form_tag` since I need the object to be accessible from the form. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote url just write this url as first form_tag parameter. Also you can add other params. Read more at  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

```
<%= form_tag('http://google.com') %>
<%= submit_tag %>
```

This code produce the next form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://google.com" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="XrSZtP4x5lzrigO9oLgCbDa04jedK6hdDrVipemle+s=" /></div>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
```